# Unable to format number in Jasper Reports

Tags: xml, jasper-reports

I am designing a PDF report with iReport 3.7.6, using an XML datasource which contains some prices (Money value), which are introduced a `textField` in my report, so I used the `pattern` `textField` property to set the currency format, but unfortunately it does not format it as i want.

Here you can see the value I want to format as currency in the XML file:

```
<importFormalitzat>1500.0</importFormalitzat>
```

This is the JRXML code for the `textField` where I display the value:

```
<textField pattern="¤ #,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement x="4" y="475" width="181" height="13"/>
    <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
       <font size="8"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Double"><![CDATA[$F{importFormalitzat} ]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

As you can see the pattern I am using to format the value is: `pattern="¤ #,##0.00"`

But the result I get when I preview the report is this: **15000,00**

I don't understand why I get 15000,00 while the value I have in the XML file from where I am filling the report is 1500.0.

I tried to change the Java class in the TextField expression to `Integer`, `BigDecimal`, but I still do not get the correct value in the report!

Comment: What datasource are you using?

Comment: an XML file that contains values such as:
 <codiFormalitzacioXGL>16/Y/215472</codiFormalitzacioXGL>
  <importFormalitzat>1500.0</importFormalitzat>
  <modalitatExecucio>Conjunta</modalitatExecucio>
  <unitatsAcceptades>0</unitatsAcceptades>
  <unitatsConcedides>0</unitatsConcedides>
  <importAcceptat>1250.19</importAcceptat

Comment: No I was asking if you where using it from java (JRXmlDataSource ) or inside jasper report... but I decided to answer both...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem of [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) and Number Pattern when you load your xml file, hence with your "Spanish" Locale the decimal separator is **,** not  **.**

You need to set correct Locale and the number pattern to your xml data source:

**In java**

```
JRXmlDataSource ds = new JRXmlDataSource("theXmlFile");
ds.setLocale(Locale.US); //Example US that uses . as decimal separator
ds.setNumberPattern("###0.00;-###0.00");//Pattern of number in xml file
```

**In iReport** (definition of the datasource)

[image: The datasource]

**EDIT:** Adding running example with its output

**XML File**

```
<report>
   <persons>
        <person>
            <name>John</name>
            <value>1500.0</value>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Marko</name>
            <value>1700.0</value>
        </person>
    </persons>
</report>
```

**JRXML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TableWithList" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="2347c131-1884-430a-b77f-59f08f896c8a">
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/report/persons/person]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="value" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[value]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="a131c9e4-a295-460f-8d9a-d7a85f0de41a"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="e39eb5aa-0687-48e8-a268-193993d647e1"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[value]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField pattern="¤ #,##0.00">
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="7c293632-3735-497e-8315-72ade69125e9"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Double"><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="83e733ca-8ad8-462c-b1b0-85b3c8b3e6f1"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

*NOTE: The field definition for `value` `class="java.lang.Double"`*

**Output**

[image: Output]